# SP error catching

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, try-catch

Can anyone recommend an improvement on the following Store Procedure code.

In the past its always been best for me to have my transaction in C# and roll back from there but now I need to have the transaction and try catch block in the SP itself.

I've found lots of examples of transaction in SP's and try catch blocks but not much of them combined.

What I'd like to know is will the code below:

1. Catch all error's
2. remove all risk of the SP crashing or timing out and leaving the transaction open and not rolled back
3. Remove all risk of the SP Committing even though an error occurred.

   ```
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SET XACT_ABORT ON; --used so transaction is not left open in the even of an error or timeout

   DECLARE @Error int

   BEGIN TRANSACTION
       BEGIN TRY

           INSERT INTO Locations_Internal (Loc_Ref, Loc_Code, Loc_Desc, Company_For_Desc, Row_Updated_PDA_Sync)
   VALUES (@Loc_Ref, @Loc_Code, @Loc_Desc, @Company_For_Desc, 'invalid value');
   SELECT @Error =@@ERROR; 
   IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER;           

   --OTHER INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE Statements

       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
           SET @Error = @@ERROR;
               GOTO ERR_HANDLER;
           END CATCH


   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   RETURN 0;       



   ERR_HANDLER:
      SELECT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      RETURN @Error
   ```

---

Thanks for the reply Manjunatha Gouli,

Would that work if the insert statement fails but doesn’t crash and throw an exception it just carries on with the rest of the procedure? Is this even possible?

I ask because most of the examples I’ve seen check @@error after every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT statement, is this approach still required when using transactions or will every error be caught by the catch rather than just continuing with the code.

Do I even need to bother checking @@ERROR with in an SP if I’m using try catch blocks? Are all the articles referring to this designed for older versions of MS SQL that didn’t implement try catch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach to address all the concerns raised by you.

BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
    INSERT INTO Locations_Internal (Loc_Ref, Loc_Code, Loc_Desc, Company_For_Desc, Row_Updated_PDA_Sync) 
        VALUES (@Loc_Ref, @Loc_Code, @Loc_Desc, @Company_For_Desc, 'invalid value');

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
RETURN 0;
```

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
    RETURN @@ERROR;
END CATCH